# Is it possible to use scoreboards from NBT number values?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, pc

I have this NBT tag on a slimeball: `{price:200}`.

How would I use `/scoreboard players remove` or something similar to that to remove coins from a player off of this value price?

So in this case it would remove 200 coins from me,
but if I changed this number to something like 1000, it should remove *1000* coins from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `execute store` to store the `price` into a fake's player score and then use the `scoreboard operation` to remove that quantity.

```
execute store result score $Price <score name> run data get entity <slime target> <nbt path>
scoreboard players operation <player target> <score name> -= $Price <score name>
```

Where `slime target` is a player with the item or the item on ground itself.

A fake player is just a username that can't be registered using special chars like `$` or `#`. This way we make sure our system will never use a real player name and it makes it more readable.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for this! I completely forgot the operation subcommand existed. Thank you so much!